# How to handle POST form data with Django (refresh avoided)?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm trying to save the form's data in a database using Django. Refreshing after click on submit button is avoided using:

**scripts.py**

```
var form = document.getElementById("mail_form_id");
function handleForm(event) { event.preventDefault(); } 
form.addEventListener('submit', handleForm);



function send_mailform(){
    console.log("cal")
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("POST", "", true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    var params = "search=" + document.getElementById('mail_input').value; 
    http.send(params);
    http.onload = function() {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
document.getElementById("mail_send_btn").addEventListener('click', send_mailform, false);
```

**views.py**

```
    #Mail check
    if request.POST:
        Marketingform = Marketingforms(request.POST)
        if Marketingform.is_valid():
            receiver_mail = Marketingform.cleaned_data['receiver_mail']

            p = mail_receiver(receiver_mail=receiver_mail)
            p.save()
            print("correct")
```

**views.py**

```
class mailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = mail_receiver
        fields =[
            'receiver_mail',
        ]
        widgets = {
            'receiver_mail': forms.EmailInput(attrs={ 'id':'mail_input', 'name':'mail_input'}),
        }
```

How can I receive the value of params in the django **views.py**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First  your ajax request is not going to work because of csrf token. you must have a request header with name: 'X-CSRFToken'  and value of the csrftoken cookie that is in the browser cookies. You must get the csrftoken cookie value and set as the header value.
Header should look like: 
**http.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', getCookie('csrftoken'));**
And getCookie() must be function to get cookie value based on its name. Django has a clean doc about this: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/
And the answer for your question is that request object contains the post data and you can have them like:
 **request.POST.get('param_name')**
This will return None if param_name doesn't exists.
Also its better to check like:
**if request.is_ajax():**instead of **if request.POST:**

Comment: And also you i think you are making a searching form that it is not necessary to have them in the form tag and prevent that from refreshing. You can simply just make a button and add an event for searching inpit and make send make your ajax request there.

Comment: I've been trying this solution and I found out (after applying the solution) that the error is here: `    if request.is_ajax(): #I've imported json but it doesnt work anyway. 
        #using request.POST() it works but I can't get the data
        Marketingform = Marketingforms(request.POST)
        if Marketingform.is_valid():`